# What is the right way to define relation one field to multiple tables (by condition)

Tags: doctrine-orm, relation

I have two Doctrine entities Order and Item. For both of these entities some related files (one or more) can be stored in database. File information is stored in File entity. I need to define relations within the File entity considering that sometimes file_owner_id can refer to record from Order table and in other cases it can refer to record from Item table. File owner is defined by the owner_type field value.

I tried to do like this

```
/**
 * UploadedFile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="uploaded_file", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="file", columns={"file"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Item\FileRepository")
 */
class File
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="owner_type", type="string", length=0, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $ownerType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Item", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $itemId;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="owner_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $orderId;

    ...

}
```

but it does not work. I've got an errors when trying to persist. So the question is if Doctrine have some way to define this type of entity relation?

Comment: What are your errors? What/how did you try to resolve them? Your use-case describes `that sometimes file_owner_id can refer to record from Order table and in other cases it can refer to record from Item table`, wouldn't that require 
 `nullable=false` for `orderId` and `itemId` (If one is set, the other isn't). Up to you to then include the logic that requires "the other" if "one" is set.

Comment: The logic you require you can (after/with above suggestion) be accomplished using a [Subscriber](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html). Give that a shot ;)

Comment: From entity definition you can see both of class properties ($itemId and $orderId) refer to the same table field `owner_id` where the file owner id is stored.

Comment: Hmmm, missed that. That's your problem. Your car is not a Fiat & Volvo, even though it's a Car type. How about you reverse this and reference to File from both Item and Order with uni-directional relationships, placing the owner where it's (seemingly) more logical?